# Return identified parts of strings with grepl rather than full string

Tags: r, string, grepl

I have a column containing around 300 strings that all end with (different) file extension.

For example

```
   id   colname1
   1    file1.mov
   2    name.jpeg
   3    bla.long_extension
```

I want to create a new string that returns only the extensions.
So everything left from the dot should be removed

```
id    new_col
 1     .mov
 2     .jpeg
 3     .long_extension
```

Using grep(".*", df$colname1, value=TRUE) I can identify which rows fit the pattern (ending in ". and an unspecified number of subsequent characters), but how can I specify that I only want the last characters returned rather than a row number or the whole string? 
Neither on the left nor on the right side of the dot the number of characters is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` to remove the prefix

```
df$new_col <- sub(".*\\.", ".", df$colname1)
df$new_col
#[1] ".mov"            ".jpeg"           ".long_extension"
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. Could you explain me the ".*\\." pattern? Basically, I know that it means "everything left to the dot." but why the first dot and the two \\?  When * indicates "The preceding item will be matched zero or more times."?